# How to get a return value from unmanaged code via COM Automation in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, com, silverlight-4.0, interop

I am currently trying to invoke some unmanaged code from a Silverlight 4 Out-Of-browser application with elevated privileges.

My simple test code fails with an ArgumentException.

```
try
{
    dynamic watch = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WatchCOMLib.HighPerformanceWatch");                

    // Displays ...AutomationMetaObjectProvider
    MessageBox.Show(watch.ToString());  


    // Fails with ArgumentException: Could not convert an argument for the call to GetTimestamp
    ulong tsc;
    watch.GetTimestamp(out tsc);  

    MessageBox.Show(tsc.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
```

I have created the COM library by using the Visual Studio 2010 ATL Template Wizard; the method looks like

```
STDMETHODIMP CHighPerformanceWatch::GetTimestamp(ULONGLONG* tsc)
{
    // ....
    *tsc = result; // result is unsigned __int64
    return S_OK;
}
```

When I simply pass tsc into GetTimestamp without specifying the out keyword, no exception is thrown, but tsc is unchanged.
Now... how can I get a value back from the unmanaged library?

Now, there may be plenty of information missing. I've followed a few Hello-World tutorials for creating this COM library, but I don't really have a clue whats goig on there. =)
Please ask for anything you need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that the IDL definition of GetTimestamp has the [out] attribute attached to the parameter?

Comment: I have now. =) Yes, the idl definition looks like `[id(1)] HRESULT GetTimestamp([out] ULONGLONG *tsc);`

Comment: This is a bit odd, as the equivalent code from C# (using Activator.CreateInstance( Type.GetTypeFromProgId ) ) works. The msdn support page for AutomationFactory.CreateObject hints that it is not fully featured with regards to marshalling parameters. It does say that it supports passing arguments by ref - this might exclude writing to memory addresses being passed in.

Comment: For a quick workaround you might want to use [retval] to return the timestamp as a return value to the function.